# Unable to load css referenced assets with wkwebview

Tags: wkwebview, swift5

Swift 5 wkwebview appears to ignore requests for relative files from css referenced assets / images / fonts. inline nor .css files work.

This happens regardless if using the local bundle paths or a website stored in its own folder in the app documents.

Javascript runs fine, however all relative file calls in css fail.

I've set the baseURL to the appropriate folder, and many direct-linked files work fine. Just not css relative pathed referenced assets.

Background images and fonts do not load when referenced in a css file using relative file paths, example:

```
background-image: url("images/background.jpg");

background-image: url("/images/background.jpg");
```

All relative referenced files fail from css calls. Checked via safari debug of the application.

In the main bundle I have an www folder where the following folder structure is:

```
www/
www/index.html ( references all support files relative path - works )
www/css/style.css ( references image and font assets relative path - fails )
www/js/main.js 
www/images/background.jpg 
www/fonts/ { various fonts }
```

This exact folder is also copied to the app's document folder to test loading from the documents folder over a main bundle resource folder. Both fail.

I've tested and verified the above web app using a node http server, no issues.

In both cases, the actual HTML loads, and relative path javascript and css files load, javascript runs fine, however all files referenced within the style.css in relative path form do not load.

Using safari on the emulated iOS device I can see the working files that are referenced are given a system file reference for loading instead of relative paths, re:

file:///Users/{ username }/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ {...device serial number... }/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/{ ... application serial ... }/webtest.app/www/css/index.css

However the failed .css referenced files are referenced as:

file:///images/background.jpg

So baseURL doesn't seem to work or is ignored?

Example funcs - both do not work regarding this issue:

```
func loadLocalURL(refDir: String, entryPt: String, ext: String, param: String? = nil) -> Void {

        let sUrl: String = entryPt + (param != nil ? "/?\(String(describing: param))" : "")

        do {

            let url = Bundle.main.url(
                forResource: sUrl,
                withExtension: ext,
                subdirectory: refDir)

            if (url != nil) {
                let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
                self.webView.load(request)
            } else {
                print("FAILED. URL: \(refDir)/\(sUrl).\(ext)")
            }


        } catch {
            print("ERROR LOADING APP AT \(refDir)\(sUrl)\nerror: \(error) ")
            return
        }

    }

    func loadLocalDocsURL(url: URL, entryPoint: String) {
        let folderURL = url.deletingPathExtension()
        let htmlPath = folderURL.appendingPathComponent(entryPoint).path
        let folderPath = folderURL.path

        let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: folderPath, isDirectory: true)

        let htmlURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath, isDirectory: false)

        self.webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false

        // self.webView.loadFileURL(htmlURL, allowingReadAccessTo: baseUrl) // Same asset relative path problem 

        self.webView.loadHTMLString(try! String(contentsOf: htmlURL), baseURL: htmlURL.deletingLastPathComponent()) // same relative path app problem

        self.view = self.webView

    }
```

Per documentation I expect that once a baseURL is set, the relative path requests should service just as if it were served via http service.

Comment: Adjusting the relative paths using "../images/background.jog" does indeed fix the problem, however this is not preferred as the web site is being copied from a live site for synchronized-then-offline use.